# Howto code a loop with condition in swift

Tags: swift

in java I can handle a loop and stop the loop with a condition in 1 line statement.

```
boolean continue=true;
for (int i=0;i<100 && continue;i++){     // <------ 1 line
```

Is this also possible in swift and when how ?

Comment: you can always use an if statement in the for loop to break

Comment: yes of course I can do, but the question is if this is possible in one line. So the answer is no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do the same but in swift continue is a key word so replace it with something different:

```
    var cont = true
    for var i = 0; i < 100 && cont; i++ {
        println("Value: \(i)")
        if i == 20 {
            cont = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. So simple, sorry for asking. I looked at a sample with for i in 0...100 {. Thanks ! I can accept in 7 minutes.